# Payment with Paypal and other credit card options

Tags: php, paypal, paypal-subscriptions, express-checkout

I am using paypal payment system for users subscription on monthly basis. All the things and flow working perfect. I need to know when user click on button and navigate to paypal site its show only pay with you paypal account or create account (pay with credit card) as shown figure

[image]

**I didn't see image like credit card option as shown in figure below.**

[image]

[image]

I'm using Digital Goods Example find on this link
https://github.com/thenbrent/paypal-digital-goods

In this example its uses SetExpressCheckout method and recurring user profile.

Its their any option or setting to enable in paypal business profile or paypal api to do that credit card payment option for users.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to have a Premier or Business account with PayPal before the option for credit card payment will show up.

If you already have a Premier or Business account, you probably have the relevant setting turned off.  Go to Profile -> Selling Preferences -> Website Payment Preferences and look for "PayPal Account Optional."  Make sure that box is checked.

If you can't find the box, click through lots of links for a while.  PayPal enjoys rearranging their website a lot.

P.S.: If you are using Sandbox mode, it won't show up. You have to be using the real Express Checkout.

Answer (score 0):

It works fine if you add these parameters when you call setExpressCheckout method:

```
SOLUTIONTYPE ="Sole"
```

**Note:** PayPal Account Optional should ON at sellers account.